# WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 vs Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was wondering what is the difference between Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver and WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32

1. Why do I need them both to run my selenium tests?
2. How do they differ?
3. For running Selenium tests on Google chrome, I need both compatible versions of these 2 nugets to the google chrome version. Is there a mapping table out there that I can find which nugets I need for each chrome version?

Answer (score -1):

What you need to run tests on chrome is:
1- chrome browser itself installed on your machine.
2- Chrome driver that matches your machine's OS architecture if it is 64 or 32. If 64 is not available, 32 will work fine.

You don't need any external thing other than those 2.